# express-session not persisting through pages

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I've made a basic website with nodejs and express that needs a session system so i used express-session to do that. The issue is that my session is not kept through the different pages of my website, it seems like the req.session is directly deleted after the login has been done.
Here is my code (just the important parts):

```
var express = require('express');
var consolidate = require('consolidate');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var session = require('express-session');
//var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

var app = express();

app.engine('html', consolidate.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(session({
  secret: "stfkjvctygf",
  resave : false,
  saveUninitialized : true,
  cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 1800000 }
}));

app.post('/login',function(req,res,next){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;
    var dbo=db.db("testdb");
    var user=dbo.collection("login").findOne({userid : req.body.userid, pwd : req.body.pwd}, function(err, user){
      if(err) throw err;
      if (user) {
        req.session.user = user;
        req.session.save(function() {
          console.log("current user session: "+req.session.user.userid);
          res.render('mainpage.html', {userid: req.session.user.userid});
        });
    }
      else {
        console.log("connection failed");
        res.render('login.html', {error: 'Invalid username or password'});
      }
      db.close();
    });
  });
});

app.get('/mainpage', function(req,res,next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.render('mainpage.html', {userid: req.session.user.userid});
  }
  else {
    return res.status(401).send();
  }
});

app.get('/profilpage', function(req,res,next){
  res.render('profilpage.html', {userid: req.session.user.userid});
});

app.listen(8080);
```

So when the log in of an user succeeds, mainpage.html is displayed properly (the field userid is correctly field with req.session.user.userid), but when I click on another page like the profilpage or if I come back to the mainpage, the session is not saved and the userid field is incorrect.
I also want to mention that the if (req.session.user) clause
in /mainpage does not work, the else seems to be never used.

(The mongodb database and html files are correct)

Thank you.

Comment: I would say when you do mongodb query and store it in user , it probably is an array, even is there is one item so you have to point to the index in that array. Do a console.log(user) after you do the query and post it here what you get.

Comment: Get rid of `var user=` in `var user = dbo.collection().findOne()`.  That's wrong and misleading.  Probably not causing your problem, but definitely wrong.

Comment: Yes of course the var user is absolutely useless it's really stupid, the log is { _id: 5ace4b3a86160808612c34df,
  name: 'Test',
  surname: 'Test',
  userid: 'Test',
  pwd: 'test',
  mail: 'test@gmail.com',
  age: '1',
  sexe: 'Undefined' }

Answer (score 0):

Delete 'var user =' because you dont need to assign the query to a variable since it is using a callback for returned data.

```
 dbo.collection("login").findOne({userid : req.body.userid, pwd : req.body.pwd}, function(err, user){
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(user) //It is most likely an array. Then use index to point the session to the username as such req.session.user = user[0].username
  if (user) {
    req.session.user = user;
    req.session.save(function() {
      console.log("current user session: "+req.session.user.userid);
      res.render('mainpage.html', {userid: req.session.user.userid});
    });
}
  else {
    console.log("connection failed");
    res.render('login.html', {error: 'Invalid username or password'});
  }
```

In addition, 'if(user)' is a bad practice, because if mongodb returns an empty array, that condition is still true, so that causes error in your logic. Its better to do something like

```
if(data.length > 0){
//your code here. data is what is returned from your mongo Query
}
```

Comment: if this answer is correct, can u please accept the answer? if not, please let me know so I can figure out another solution. Thanks

Comment: While the `var user = ` is definitely wrong, I don't think it actually fixes anything to remove it because the `user` in the callback `function(err, user)` overrides that other `user` definition.

Comment: Yeah thats true, he can just change it to data so 'function (err,data)

Comment: Thanks. Yes doing a var user is absolutely wrong I don't know why I did that, I just removed it and I also changed the if(user). But the problem is still there. Maybe it is related to the use of a post and not a get method.

Comment: I tried but got an error: ReferenceError: userid is not defined. So I used req.session.user = user.userid and req.session.user  = req.body.userid but the problem is still there, the session is not persistent.

Comment: Well as mentioned before, the query returns an array so use req.session.user = data[0].userid ;